# Como fazer um SELECT com CONVERT ou CAST na cláusula WHERE usando sequelize

Tags: sql-server, sequelize-js

Preciso fazer o select abaixo usando sequelize.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM Table
WHERE 
    CAST(DatetimeField AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Até agora consegui fazer usando **between** mas não é a melhor forma de fazer isso:

```
return model.findAll({
    attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('*')), alias]
    ],
    where: {
        CreationDate: {
            $between: ['2017-09-15 00:00:00', '2017-09-15 23:59:59']
        }
    }
});
```

Podem ajudar?